# FormData is not defined / axios / jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, axios

I'm testing my axios based service by sending FormData but Jest gives me a `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined`

Can't figure out why - it should be in jsdom???

The test is a integration-test, so it should make a real request to the rest backend. I can't (want) mock the call...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My testing file:

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom")
const jsdom = new JSDOM('')

describe('Something...', () => {
  it('should api do something... ',
    const formData = new jsdom.window.FormData()
    ...
```